# Problem with connect exist nginx container and new wordpress container

Tags: wordpress, docker, nginx, docker-compose

The nginx container works for me. It works great. But now I need to add a new container with WordPress from another docker-compose.yml file.

After creating a new container, my site does not work from port 80 and gives me error 502 Bad Gateway. Port 8000 works fine.

**wordpres-docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: mysql_5_7
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${ROOT_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DB_NAME}
      MYSQL_USER: ${DB_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
    networks:
      - app-network

  wordpress:
    image: wordpress:latest
    container_name: my_site
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - app-network
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
    restart: always
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: ${DB_NAME}
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: ${DB_USER}
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}

networks:
  app-network:
    external: true

volumes:
  db_data:
```

**nginx-docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: docker_nginx
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - ./conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
      - /home/user/www/:/usr/local/www/
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    external_links:
      - my_site
    networks:
      - app-network

networks:
  app-network:
    external: true
```

**site-nginx.conf**

```
upstream mysite{
  server site:8000;
}

server {
        listen 0.0.0.0:80;
        server_name www.site.com site.com;

        access_log /usr/local/www/site/log/nginx.access.log;
        error_log /usr/local/www/site/log/nginx.error.log;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://mysite;
                client_max_body_size 100M;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need release all nested app without ports.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `server site:8000;` in your `site-nginx.conf` file should be `server my_site:8000;` due to the `container_name` you defined.